# align text center in a right floated div

Tags: css

I have a div which has css style float:right.
The problem is, I want to align some text in the div to be in center. However, the text is always at left side. I use text-align:center but it useless.
I appreciate for any help. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<div style='float:right'>
     <span style='text-align:center'>some text...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `display:block;` to the span element .. here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/PpY8E/1/)

Answer (score 0):

make the span a div and it will work (I just gave the container a `width` and a `border`, so that you can see the effect better):

```
<div style='float:right; width:200px; border:1px solid #000'>
    <div style='text-align:center'>some text...</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RN6nf/)

Answer (score 0):

To `text-align:center` the text inside a floated `div`, the width of the width should be greater than the containing element. 
For example: assume your `span` tag has some text which occupies `100px`. When you `float` the parent element to `left` or `right`, it will be floated correspondingly and takes the width as `100px` because you haven't specified a width for it. So specify a `width` for it, in you case the `div` which is floated left.

Try this:

```
<div style='float:right; width:200px; text-align:center;background:red;'>
     <span style='text-align:center'>some text...</span>
</div>
```

You can remove the `background-color` since i gave it for reference.

**OR**

You can even specify a width for the element which you want to center align. In your case since `span` is an inline element, you have to specify a `width` and also give it `display:block`

```
<div style='float:right; background:red;'>
     <span style='text-align:center; width: 200px; display:block;'>some text...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: span with `display:block` is bad idea

Comment: @Pilot yes you are right. Just for knowing, would it be fine if we use the span class as block in other cases like inside an inline element to set some icons or something?

Comment: No...`img` is `replaced inline element` ..You can use block element for this purpose like `div` ..dont set span as `block` element..`display:table` more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to but text-align:center in th div

see this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/PpY8E/)**
css

```
div
 {
float: right;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: solid 1px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have never defined a width for the div. So the text is centered, because the div is only as wide as the text. Try giving the div a width of 50% (or how ever wide you want it) then applying text-align:center.

```
<div style='float:right;width:50%;text-align:center;'>
 <span>some text...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set display: block for the span tag

```
<div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid gray;">
     <span style="text-align: center; display: block;">some text...</span>
</div>
```